# Is it possible to configure Google Lighthouse to test on Desktop device using command line?

Tags: reactjs, lighthouse

Google Lighthouse seems to be doing the audit test on mobile whenever I run

```
lighthouse http://localhost:3000/my-app
```

Is it possible to configure it such that it runs the test on Desktop?

Comment: `--preset=desktop` should do it!